# mongocxx SegFault mac os x

Tags: macos, c++11, mongo-cxx-driver

I installed mongo-c and mongocxx as instructed.
pkg-config out:

```
pkg-config --cflags libmongocxx
-I/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi -I/usr/local/Cellar/mongo-c-driver/1.9.0/include/libmongoc-1.0 -I/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi -I/usr/local/Cellar/mongo-c-driver/1.9.0/include/libbson-1.0
```

CMake:

```
set(CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS "${CMAKE_CXX_FLAGS} -std=c++11")
###MONGODB
include_directories(${libmongocxx_INCLUDE_DIRS})
find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
find_package(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)
include_directories(${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories(${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIR})
include_directories("/usr/local/include/mongocxx/v_noabi")
include_directories("/usr/local/include/bsoncxx/v_noabi")
include_directories("/usr/local/include/libmongoc-1.0")
include_directories("/usr/local/include/libbson-1.0")
include_directories("/usr/local/lib")
find_package(Boost REQUIRED COMPONENTS thread system)


add_executable(1MongoTest 1MongoTest.cpp)
```

The basic Code:

```
 #include <cstdint>
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
#include <bsoncxx/json.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/client.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/stdx.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/uri.hpp>
#include <mongocxx/instance.hpp>
#include <string>


using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::close_document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::document;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::finalize;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_array;
using bsoncxx::builder::stream::open_document;

using namespace std;

int main(int argc, char **argv) {


    mongocxx::instance instance{}; // This should be done only once.
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
    mongocxx::client client(uri);

    mongocxx::database db = client["mydb"];
    mongocxx::collection coll = db["test"];

    std::cout << "passed " << endl;


    return 0;
```

I am getting segmentation fault when I run.

The problem line is:

```
    mongocxx::uri uri("mongodb://localhost:27017");
```

What am I doing wrong ?  I am following the exact steps at the official site.?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

I figure out the problem..

I am using c++7 . and its incompatible with this compile/build.

When I fall back to c++ . all is went well...

this is the cmake:

```
    add_executable(1MongoTest 1MongoTest.cpp)

find_package(libmongocxx REQUIRED)
find_package(libbsoncxx REQUIRED)


target_link_libraries(1MongoTest ${LIBMONGOCXX_LIBRARIES})
target_link_libraries(1MongoTest ${LIBBSONCXX_LIBRARIES})

target_include_directories(1MongoTest PUBLIC ${LIBBSONCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
target_include_directories(1MongoTest PUBLIC ${LIBMONGOCXX_INCLUDE_DIRS})
```

Comment: Do you mean that you are using C++17 and it didn't work? What version of the driver are you using? I made several changes that landed in 3.2.0-rc0 that improved C++17 support, so it should work fine. Also, what choice of polyfill are you using when you build the driver, and what toolchain?

Comment: Nope. I used   c++-7 (Homebrew GCC 7.2.0) 7.2.0 and it gave the errors.
Than fall back to : Apple LLVM version 9.0.0 (clang-900.0.38)
Target: x86_64-apple-darwin16.7.0..  Than all is ok.  It took me hours.........

Comment: Calling it c++7 is going to confuse people. GCC 7 is a compiler and toolchain version, c++17 is a language, c++7 looks... strange.

Comment: With homebrew installed C driver 1.9.0 via `brew install mongo-c-driver && brew link mongo-c-driver`, along with GCC 7.2 installed from homebrew, I was able to build 3.2.0-rc1 from source like this `cmake -G Ninja .. -DCMAKE_BUILD_TYPE=Release -DCMAKE_C_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/gcc-7 -DCMAKE_CXX_COMPILER=/usr/local/Cellar/gcc/7.2.0/bin/g++-7`. Everything worked fine. Can you post the errors you are seeing when you use GCC 7, and provide the git hash or version of the driver you are building?

Comment: I will try to reproduce the error through a virtual machine.  But the error not from the compiling the mongoc and mongocxx .  All looks compiled fine. But when I try to run above code it gave the Segmentation Fault. I tried a lot of thing. Finally I decide to fallback to LLVM CLANG 9  instead of the GCC-7 recompiled everything an then all is fine. It took whole day because there was no enlightening error message.

Comment: On the other hand I am 7 year java and 5 year scala guy. C++ is whole new world for me. Very different...